# Change html video players css through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide the gradient and the timeline from the HTML video player trough jquery/javascript.

I got it to work on CSS:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    background-image: none !important;
    filter: brightness(0);
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
```

But the CSS should only be there once the video has a source so I want to add this CSS trough javascript. This allows me to add conditions.

I've tried the following, but nothing seem to change when doing this:

```
$('video::-webkit-media-controls-panel').css({
    'background-image': 'none !important',
    'filter': 'brightness(0)'
});

$('video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline').css({
    'display': 'none'
});
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: why not just write it in a global `.css` or within a `<style></style>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by appending a `style` tag to the head via JavaScript with the intended styles you provided. The ES6 template literal syntax was used to keep things looking clean. Tested in Chrome.

[image]

```
$(`<style>
    video::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
    video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline{display: none;} 
    video::-webkit-media-controls-panel{background-image:none !important}    
   </style>`).appendTo('head');
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x04z2cqk/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution to Andy's but works with an editor, like Atto in Moodle, which automatically removes <style>:

```
var sty = document.createElement("style");
sty.innerHTML = "video::-webkit-media-controls-panel { background-image: none !important; filter: brightness(0); } video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline { display: none; }";
$("head").append(sty);
```